# WPFToolkit AccordionItem does not resize to dynamically sized content

Tags: wpf, xaml, accordion, wpftoolkit

I've reported an issue on project's site here https://github.com/dotnetprojects/WpfToolkit/issues/21, but someone might have a workaround for this. It seems like an inherent problem with ContentPresenter responding only to Content change but not tracking its size.

```html
        <controls:AccordionItem Header="item1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <Button x:Name="button" Height="100" Width="200" Click="Button_OnClick">Grow Me</Button>
        </controls:AccordionItem>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `Accordion.Height += button.ActualHeight;`?

Comment: It's been fixed in the the fork mentioned above